# analysis of Tree Algorithm height

Tags: algorithm

in Data Structures Book The author explain the analysis of this code

```
int height2(const Tree& T, const Position& p) {
    if (p.isExternal()) return 0; 
    int h = 0;
    PositionList ch = p.children(); // iterate on the children of the node
    for (Iterator q = ch.begin(); q != ch.end(); ++q)
        h = max(h, height2(T, *q));
    return 1 + h;
}
```

as it take 1 + c<sub>p</sub> (c<sub>p</sub> denote the number of children of the node) for each node
But why we don't say it take c<sub>p</sub> for "children" function and c<sub>p</sub> for the while loop to be (c<sub>p</sub> + c<sub>p</sub>) for each node ?
Here's the author explain for the analysis
[image]

Comment: The O notation eats up constant factors, so O(2*x)=O(x). It also eats up the +1, so I'm not sure why the authors bother to write it down.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
PositionList ch = p.children(); // iterate on the children of the node
for (Iterator q = ch.begin(); q != ch.end(); ++q)
```

`p.children()` is of O(1) cost because it is just a function that returns an iterator (say a pointer to the first children).
It is the `for` loop that takes O(c_p).

Comment: That's want a sensible implementation would do, but that's not what the book says.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI explanations are refereing to a `children℗` function and  a while loop, which does not correspond to what is in algorithm `Height2`. Something is missing or there is some mistake somewhere.

Comment: OP provides a screenshot from the book. It says literally "processing each node in children(p) takes O(cp) time". If you believe there is an error in that specific statement, or that there is some other statement that is missing from the screenshot and that would somehow nullify the quoted statement, you probably should say so in your answer.